# Strange behaviour of clientHeight in ie10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I try to check property clientHeight by this code:

```
document.documentElement != null && document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty('clientHeight')
```

and the result is false because of document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty('clientHeight') 
but when i check it by `'clientHeight' in document.documentElement` it return true. In Chrome,FF,Opera all works fine. What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: An object has a property doesn't necessary mean that property is "owned" by that object; it can be in the prototype chain.

Comment: I thought about it, but hoped that they will not reinvent the wheel=)

Answer (score 2):

Not answering your question (*what is the reason* for this), but still want to share, so extending from comment:

An object with a property doesn't necessary mean that property is "owned" by that object; it can be in the prototype chain.

Check about this (in Chrome DevTools console):

```
Object.create({"foo":"bar"}).hasOwnProperty("foo")
false
"foo" in Object.create({"foo":"bar"})
true
```

So as you can see, `foo` does exist in the created object, but it's not "owned" by the object, just sits in the prototype chain.

When talk about DOM prototype, things can be a little bit more complicated as different platform may implement the same thing differently.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element#Properties), `clientHeight` is defined in `Element.prototype`, so

in Firefox's console, I got:

```
[17:09:55.701] document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty("clientHeight")
[17:09:55.702] false
--
[17:10:19.894] "clientHeight" in document.documentElement
[17:10:19.895] true
```

but in Opera Dragonfly console, I got:

```
>>> document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty("clientHeight")
true
>>> "clientHeight" in document.documentElement
true
```

and in Chrome DevTools console, I got:

```
document.documentElement.hasOwnProperty("clientHeight")
true
"clientHeight" in document.documentElement
true
```

(No IE10 for me to test right now, but if I remember correctly, IE10 follows Firefox style)

So it seems in Chrome and Opera, `clientHeight` is defined "per element", not in `Element.prototype`. Go a little further and you can see:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.documentElement)
HTMLHtmlElement {insertAdjacentHTML: function, insertAdjacentText: function, click: function, insertAdjacentElement: function, getAttribute: function…}
    constructor: function HTMLHtmlElement() { [native code] }
    __proto__: HTMLElement
        click: function click() { [native code] }
        constructor: function HTMLElement() { [native code] }
        insertAdjacentElement: function insertAdjacentElement() { [native code] }
        insertAdjacentHTML: function insertAdjacentHTML() { [native code] }
        insertAdjacentText: function insertAdjacentText() { [native code] }
        __proto__: Element
```

As to your problem, I would say, whatever you're trying to accomplish, don't depend on this "standard", use feature detection.

---

I first noticed this behavior when I tried to clone object in JS.

When trying to clone a `ClientRect` object (e.g. `document.body.getBoundingClientRect()`), when I want to go a little bit fancy, I first tried:

```
var cloned={};
if(cloned.__proto__) {
    cloned.__proto__=source.__proto__;
}
for(var i in source) {
    if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source,i)){
        cloned[i]=source[i];
    }
}
```

In Chrome it works fine, but in Firefox the `cloned` looks like `{width:undefined,height:undefined...}`. So I changed the `for..in` to this:

```
for(var in source) {
    cloned[i]=source[i];
}
```

In Firefox this gave me an Exception at the very first `i` because those 6 properties are read only.

After some failure I concluded that `ClientRect` in Firefox is not constructible, so not strictly, perfectly cloneable.

Comment: I do not know if I was waiting for the ie developers in this thread. Probably should ask how to make it cross browser(just use in). But your answer is certainly very good.

Comment: @Suhan May I ask why you _need_ the `clientHeight` to be in `document.documentElement`'s own property?

Comment: It seemed to me that this should be a property of the object, and not all objects. It took a little time before I realized that it is not =)