# Cannot see javascript object properties in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I run this function in Firefox (Firefox 20, Linux) I just see `{};{}`:

```
es.addEventListener('error', function(e){document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML+="ERR:"+JSON.stringify(e)+";"+JSON.stringify(es)+"<br/>";},false);
```

BTW, `es` is an `EventSource` object, and `e` is an `Event` object.

So, I tried this alternative:

```
function objToString (obj) {
    var str = '';
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str += p + '::' + obj[p] + '\n';
        }
    }
    return str;
}

//...

es.addEventListener('error', function(e){document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML+="ERR:"+objToString(e)+";"+objToString(es)+"<br/>";},false);
```

And still get nothing output. So I tried this approach, and still get nothing, both for toString() and for the keys. (`toSource()` was the same too.)

```
es.addEventListener('error', function(e){document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML+="ERR:"+e.toString()+";"+Object.keys(e).toString()+";"+es.toString()+";"+Object.keys(es).toString()+"<br/>";},false);
```

Still nothing. This seemed unfair, as by using Firebug to set a breakpoint, I could see both objects had lots of properties. Then I tried in Chrome, and discovered all three techniques work. And all three also work in Opera.

So, what is going on with Firefox? Is there some limitation with viewing the properties of built-in objects? Is it a security thing that I can override by setting some Firefox property?

---

NOTE: the post that was earlier marked as a duplicate ([How to get error event details in Firefox using addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746034/how-to-get-error-event-details-in-firefox-using-addeventlistener)) is a different question. I can access `e.type`, `es.url`, etc. in all browsers, including Firefox. What is different in Firefox is that es.toString() returns an empty string, JSON.stringify sees an empty object, Object.Keys(es) returns an empty array, etc.

Comment: Apparently this only works in Webkit:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746034/how-to-get-error-event-details-in-firefox-using-addeventlistener

Comment: `Trivial answer converted to comment` :(  Anyway, it's a dupe...

Comment: @Steve I just edited my question to explain that the one you linked to is asking something different. The fields are there, if you know their names. But Object.Keys() et al, do not see them.

Comment: Because you're using `if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p))`, and when talking about DOM-related properties, Firefox uses different "schema" than WebKit/Presto. Many DOM-related properties in Gecko sits in the prototype chain, not in the object itself. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16810390/570812

Comment: @Passerby Thanks, that makes sense. A quick test shows commenting out the `obj.hasOwnProperty(p)` line from `objToString` shows the data (and a bit of noise: all the constants). I think your comment answers my question, so if you post it as an answer I can give you the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, extending from comment:

Because in Firefox/Gecko, many DOM-related properties sits in prototype chain, not in object instance's own property (e.g. `clientHeight` in `Element.prototype`, not in any element instance), so `obj.hasOwnProperty(p)` will false, and `Object.keys` will return an empty array.

Compare

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(document.documentElement)
```

In Chrome:

```
HTMLHtmlElement {insertAdjacentHTML: function, insertAdjacentText: function, click: function, insertAdjacentElement: function, getAttribute: function…}
    constructor: function HTMLHtmlElement() { [native code] }
    __proto__: HTMLElement
        click: function click() { [native code] }
        constructor: function HTMLElement() { [native code] }
        /*... all native functions */
        __proto__: Node
```

In Firefox:

(list all constants, properties, methods in plain first-level; heck, Firefox's native console result is hard to copy).